# Volume of a wine barrel

Tags: calculus

This is a famous calculus problem and is stated like this

> Given a barrel with height $h$, and a small radius of $a$ and
>   large radius of $b$. Calculate the volume of the barrel 
>   given that the sides are parabolic. 
>   [image: Barrel]

Now I seem to have solved the problem incorrectly because here it seems [[2](http://www.onlineconversion.com/object_volume_barrel.htm)](http://www.onlineconversion.com/object_volume_barrel.htm)
that the volume should be

$ \displaystyle \hspace{1cm}
   V(a,b,h) = \frac{h\pi}{3}\left(2b^2 + a^2\right)\,.
$

Below is my attempt. As in the picture I view the barrel from the side, and try to find a formula for the parabola. So i solve

$ \displaystyle \hspace{1cm}
    f(x) := A x^2 + B x + C 
$

given $f(0) = f(h) = a/2$ and $f(h/2) = b/2$. This yields

$ \displaystyle \hspace{1cm}
f(x) =  \frac{2(a-b)}{h^2} \cdot  x^2 - 
        \frac{2(a-b)}{h} \cdot x + 
       \frac{a}{2}
$

Using the shell method integrating now gives the volume as

$ \displaystyle \hspace{1cm}
    V(a,b,h) := \pi \int_0^h \bigl[f(x)\bigr]^2\,\mathrm{d}x
              = \frac{\pi}{60} \cdot h (a+2b)^2 + \frac{\pi}{30} \cdot h(a^2+b^2)
$

Alas according to the formula above this seems incorrect! Where is my mistake?

Comment: Put $a=b$, then your formula gives $\pi h a^2 \frac{13}{60}$... The integration seems to be off

Comment: Yeah, I thought that $a$ and $b$ were the diameters for the barrel, and not the radii. Scaling them solved the problem.

Comment: The calculation was perhaps unnecessarily heroic. Let $k=h/2$. Put the origin in the middle, where it is meant to be. Our (upper) parabola is then $y=b-\frac{b-a}{k^2}x^2$. Square, integrate from $0$ to $k$. and double.

Comment: Great! Has the question about the partially filled barrel been asked on the site before? Eg how to measure how much liquid is in sideways barrel. (Put a hole in the middle and use a stick).

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar Actually... did it solve the problem? Your integral was missing an extra $2$ in the last bracket (i.e. $(a^2+2b^2)$ instead of $(a^2+b^2)$); then it would have been right. However, it would **not** be equal to the formula from the external site (even after correction for the radii vs. diameters mistake)! The one you quoted is only an easier-to-remember-approximation. The actual formula for parabolic barrel can be seen [here](http://www.had2know.com/academics/barrel-volume-equation-calculator.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $k=h/2$, and put the origin in the middle, where symmetry asks it to be.

Then the equation of the upper parabola is 
$$y=b-\frac{b-a}{k^2}x^2.$$
The integral of $\pi y^2\,dx$ from $0$ to $k$ is 
$$\pi k\left(b^2-\frac{2}{3}(b-a)b+\frac{1}{5}(b-a)^2\right).$$
This simplifies to 
$$\frac{\pi k}{15}(3a^2+4ab+8b^2)$$
Replace $k$ by $h/2$ and multiply by $2$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in their case $a$, $b$ are radiuses, not diameters. Another important thing to say  is that **the formula from that external site is not exact!**

For simplicity, take $h=1$. Let's define our function on $[-1/2,1/2]$ as $f(x) = 4(a-b)x^2+b$. We write

$$\frac{V}{\pi}= 2\int _{0}^{1/2}(4(a-b)x^2+b)^2 \mathrm dx= 16 (a-b)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{5\cdot 16}+ 8 b(a-b)\cdot \frac{1}{3\cdot 4} + b^2$$
$$=  (a-b)^2/5 + 2 b(a-b)/3  + b^2.$$

Answer (score -1):

Volume of a barrel

V = 0.5 * πQuadrat * (π/18 + 1/6) * (r1Quadrat + r2Quadrat) * h parabolic bend
V = 0.5 * πQuadrat * (π/17 + 1/6) * (r1Quadrat + r2Quadrat) * h elliptic bend

Best regards
Hans-Jürgen Gläsel

Comment: r1 and r2: radius 1 and 2, respectively

Comment: Both equations are good approximation formulas