# Semi filled barrel - pt 2

Tags: calculus

Assume we have another barrel. This time it is made of a material 
which is not transparent, and the barrel is too heavy to raise.
Still you want to measure how much liquid is in the barrel using a stick.

Given the barrel has a smaller radius $r$, a larger radius $R$ and a height of $h$.

If the amount of liquid on the stick is $z$, what is the volume of the barrel?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/yTLrB.png]

Using this answer [Volume of a wine barrel](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/445326/volume-of-a-wine-barrel), the volume of the barrel has been calculated. But I am unsure on how to use this to calculate the volume when the barrel is semi filled.

Comment: Half-full shouldn't be a problem, if the bung hole is in the middle. For other heights, we need to find the area of cross-section and integrate. It is a little unpleasant, since there are a few cases.

Comment: I am desperately searching for an answer to the same question. So far the closest I have come is in the following: http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonneau_(formules)
The section "Volume pariel en fonction de la hauteur de liquide" is exactly the question you and I are asking but the formula given seems to leave me with an integration I am not capable of performing if in fact it is correct which seems questionable when I compare it to the user-friendly formula given for the simpler case of a horizontal cylinder http://snovae.free.fr/spip.php?article393&lang=fr.

Answer (score 0):

Remember how you calculate the area of the segment on the circle? You first calculate the sector by multiplying the angle with the area of the circle. Then subtract the triangle.

Same thing here. You know the volume of the whole barrel. Angle can be calculated from $z$ using trigonometry ($\cos(\frac{\theta}{2})=\frac{z}{R}$). Thus you can calculate the volume of the barrel version of a sector. Then calculate the volume of the prism (which is the barrel version of the triangle). And the rest is done.